# cloned ubuntu drive can't get on network

Tags: networking

I set up ubuntu a while back and used it just fine.   After setting it up, which was a real pain for some reason, I made an exact clone of the drive and put it on the shelf so I wouldn't have to set it up again if I needed another box. Today I put the clone drive in another computer and it worked but wouldn't connect to the network.

Is there anything in Ubuntu that would conflict on the network with another exact copy?

If so, how do I change that "thing"?

If not, any ideas why it won't connect when it's exact copy works.

I can't take the original off the network for a few days but I'm wondering if I do, whether the clone would then work.

> The following information was requested in a comment and was added after the original post:
>
> The original computer:

```
 pcw@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp

 pcw@ubuntu:~$
```

> The clone computer (the computer hardware for the 2 are exactly the
>   same):

```
 pcw@ubuntu2:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth1
 iface eth1 inet dhcp

 pcw@ubuntu2:~$
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (from 2014.April) had 5 years of supported life, it's now EOL & thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). If you're using Ubuntu 14.04 ESM which is still supported by Canonical; all ESM releases are off-topic here so use your Ubuntu Advantage support options.

Comment: 16.04.5 and 18.04.2 LTS are currently supported, as is 19.04.

Comment: Probably because you need to change the hostname. And yes, having both old/new on the network at the same time causes this problem. Also, if you're using Access Control lists in your router, you'll have to add the new MAC address.

Comment: SOLVED.  Thank you @heynnema for recognizing that this is a non-version specific issue.  I want to give my solution to help others who may find themselves in the same situation.  It is correct that the same hostname would have caused a problem had I got on the network, so I edited /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts to change hostname but it still didn't work.  Searching for similar problems, I found that by using 'sudo lshw -C network' I could see the network device logical name - it was eth1 but on the initial computer it was eth0 so I changed it in /etc/network/interfaces and everything now works.

Comment: @pcw actually, removing eth1 from /etc/network/interfaces would be best. Is the hardware slightly different on the 2nd computer? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` as it is now. Then I'll write up an answer that you can accept, if it was helpful. OK?

Comment: @heynnema Done.

Comment: @PCW quickie answer done.

Comment: @guiverc  Kind Sir.  On 6/23 my above post was put [on hold] by you and 4 others because it related to an unsupported Ubuntu release. The notice indicated that I could edit the post to bring it into compliance. I did so on 6/24 yet days later [on hold] changed to [closed] without the date changing so it looks like I edited the post after the notice but it was actually before.  As of this point, the post has been viewed 74 times and does provide a useful answer to the community. The post can remain closed, but the reason - "appears to be off-topic for this site" - should be removed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Probably because you need to change the hostname.

- It is correct that the same hostname would have caused a problem had I got on the network, so I edited `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` to change hostname.

As you found out, if you use `/etc/network/interfaces` to describe your network hardware, it makes a difference what your network interfaces are named.

- Then you changed eth0 to eth1 in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Your current `/etc/network/interfaces` (currently working):

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth1
 iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

I'd recommend trying (more transportable, less dependent):

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
```